# PHP regex match all bible references not working

Tags: php, regex

I'm currently struggling with a regular expression to match all bible quotes in body text so I can convert them into links. I was hoping someone could please help out with this issue as I'm new to regex. So far I am using this:

```
/([^(])\w+ +\d+:+[\d+[?\-]+([^)])/
```

Some example text looks like this:

```
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sea persius nonumes habemus cu. Eam ferri dicta ex, sit no torquatos reprimique. Ea tota democritum has, mel libris audiam voluptaria cu. Ex usu facer voluptatibus, nam ut commune democritum. Ea nonumes  (1 John 3:1) recteque sapientem eum. Cum soleat mandamus te, (Matthew 6:6) eos affert volutpat et.

Quo ei iracundia consectetuer. Vim salutatus abhorreant at, quo ea postea equidem intellegam. Duo dicit cotidieque id, debitis noluisse fabellas sit eu. Qui ne integre patrioque, minimum inciderint eos ex, aliquando (Deuteronomy 10:18; Psalm 10:14) tincidunt intellegat est at. Sumo assum et nec, usu graecis adversarium te, cu mea quis lorem. In qui utroque propriae, ex mandamus argumentum vis, pro vidisse ceteros atomorum ex. Et mentitum referrentur
```

My regex is individually matching most of the quotes in my pages so far, including the example text but(1 John 3:1) and (Matthew 6:6) don't work. The regex needs to match an opening brace and omit it from the resulting string then match an optional number with a space and or a word (book name) followed by a space and a number (chapter) followed by a colon (:) then a number with an optional dash (-) and another number (verses), followed by an optional semicolon (;) if there are multiple references, followed by a closing brace (omit this from the resulting match). What do I update in order to match my desire criteria?

Example code:

```
<?php
$body = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sea persius nonumes habemus cu. Eam ferri dicta ex, sit no torquatos reprimique. Ea tota democritum has, mel libris audiam voluptaria cu. Ex usu facer voluptatibus, nam ut commune democritum. Ea nonumes  (1 John 3:1) recteque sapientem eum. Cum soleat mandamus te, (Matthew 6:6) eos affert volutpat et.

        Quo ei iracundia consectetuer. Vim salutatus abhorreant at, quo ea postea equidem intellegam. Duo dicit cotidieque id, debitis noluisse fabellas sit eu. Qui ne integre patrioque, minimum inciderint eos ex, aliquando (Deuteronomy 10:18; Psalm 10:14) tincidunt intellegat est at. Sumo assum et nec, usu graecis adversarium te, cu mea quis lorem. In qui utroque propriae, ex mandamus argumentum vis, pro vidisse ceteros atomorum ex. Et mentitum referrentur";

    $template_body = preg_replace_callback(
            '/([^(])\w+ +\d+:+[\d+[?\-]+([^)])/',
            function ($matches) {
                $replacement = '<a href="https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search='.$matches[0].';&version=NIVUK">'.$matches[0].'</a>';
                return $replacement;
            },
            $body
        );
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about: `[ (](([0-9] )?[\w]+ [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2})[;)]` ?

https://regex101.com/r/Y4nasm/3

**Details**

`[ (]`: match a space or `(`

`([0-9] )?`: optionally match a number followed by a space

`[\w]+`: matches any word character

`[0-9]{1,2}`: match a number of length 1 or 2

`[;)]`: match a `;` or `(`

Comment: Nice work, thank you :) I'll spend some more time brushing up on this as it's an area I d not have much experience in.

Comment: ok, so I ended up with this to add the optional dash and verse eg (Mark 1:1-5)  [ (](([0-9] )?[\w]+ [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}(-[0-9]{1,2})?)[;)]

Comment: For Psalms you will need `[0-9]{1,3}` (instead of `{1,3}`) for the chapters, and in particular for Ps 119 you will also need `{1,3}` for verses.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to include the parentheses in your match, because that will make it hard to match the second reference in "(Deuteronomy 10:18; Psalm 10:14)". Instead, use zero-width assertions to specify that your match should be preceded and followed by either a `(` or `;` without matching it. `(?<=[(;])` for the prefix and `(?=[(;])` for the suffix.

Semicolons are followed by spaces but open parentheses are not, so there's optional whitespace `(\s*)` after the prefix. This is in parentheses because it will be the first match in your expression, and we'll output it before the `<a>...</a>` tag.

I've not changed a lot else. I replaced  with `\s` throughout in case there happens to be other whitespace. I don't think it's worth restricting the number of digits matched but if you do I'd go with at least `{1,3}` because there are more than 100 psalms and some chapters have lots of verses.

In the output I suggest URL encoding the search text in the link and I've removed a `;` character which looked unnecessary.

```
$body =
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sea persius nonumes habemus cu. Eam ferri dicta"
    . " ex, sit no torquatos reprimique. Ea tota democritum has, mel libris"
    . " audiam voluptaria cu. Ex usu facer voluptatibus, nam ut commune"
    . " democritum. Ea nonumes  (1 John 3:1) recteque sapientem eum. Cum soleat"
    . " mandamus te, (Matthew 6:6) eos affert volutpat et. Quo ei iracundia"
    . " consectetuer. Vim salutatus abhorreant at, quo ea postea equidem"
    . " intellegam. Duo dicit cotidieque id, debitis noluisse fabellas sit eu."
    . " Qui ne integre patrioque, minimum inciderint eos ex, aliquando"
    . " (Deuteronomy 10:18; Psalm 10:14) tincidunt intellegat est at. Sumo assum"
    . " et nec, usu graecis adversarium te, cu mea quis lorem. In qui utroque"
    . " propriae, ex mandamus argumentum vis, pro vidisse ceteros atomorum ex."
    . " Et mentitum referrentur";

$template_body = preg_replace_callback(
    '[(?<=[(;])(\s*)((\d+\s+)?\w+\s+\d+:\d+(-\d+)?)(?=[);])]',
    function ($matches) {
        $replacement = $matches[1]
            . '<a href="https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search='
            . rawurlencode($matches[2]) . '&version=NIVUK">'
            . $matches[2] . '</a>';
        return $replacement;
    },
    $body
);
```

Comment: Cheers, Matt :)

Answer (score 0):

I struggled to find a great solution, and ended up with this: https://regexr.com/67870

```
/\b([1|2|3]{1}[ ]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2,11}|[a-zA-Z]{2,11})\s([0-9]{1,3})\:([0-9]{1,3})(?: {0,1}[\-,] {0,1}([0-9]{1,3}))?\b/gi
```

It matches Bible verses, with and without ranges! No leading spaces for Books that don't begin with a number!

Tested with formats like this:

- Genesis 5:1
- Genesis 5:1-10
- Genesis 5:1 - 10
- 1 John 1:1
- 1 John 1:1-10
- 1 John 1:1 - 10